# Clojure: Compare an operator to list element (data)

Tags: if-statement, clojure

I want to code a simple derivative solver. Therefore I need some code that is capable of checking which operator is used, but I just can't get it to work. I'm a newbie in clojure so I might overlook some important basic thing here .. :)

This is some test code:

```
(defn get-input []
'(* x y))

(println (get-input))
(println (first (get-input)))

(println 
    (if (= * (first (get-input)))  
        "Y"
        "N"))
```

This yields the following output:

```
(* x y)
*
N
```

As you can see, the first element of the input list is an asterisk, but the *if* special form yields false (and therefore "N" is printed). How can I modify the *if* to check if that first element of the list is indeed an asterisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item of that list is not the function referred to by `*`, but the symbol named `*`, which you can get by quoting it:

```
(if (= '* (first (get-input)))
  ...)
```

Comment: thanks. i tried it with '(*) which clearly generated a list of *